# ASP.net Disallow Direct Access to Admin Directory

Tags: asp.net, security, routes

We have a directory named Admin in the root folder of an ASP.net (4.0) web application.

I have created a route to the Admin/Dashboard.aspx

> ~/administrator/dashboard/

and it works fine.

I was curious if I could disallow to run the file through direct access, even to the administrators.

> ~/Admin/Dashboard.aspx

Is it doable?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with some web.config setting like below

```
<location path="~/Admin/Dashboard.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="admin"/>
<deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: I want to disallow access to the file completely via direct access. Does this hurt the route?

Comment: @Nancy Are you using MVC architecture ?
if yes then look out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370315/asp-net-mvc-restricting-access-using-url

if no then http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405394/using-routing-without-mvc-authentication-form

Comment: Then you can refer my 2nd link

Answer (score 0):

Create a local `web.config` in the `Admin` folder and create an authorization rule inside the config file:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <allow ...
      <deny ...
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

where `allow` and `deny` should be tuned to serve your needs. In particular, `deny users="*"` will forbid everyone from accessing your page.